# Landstalker 2 or a "Look Like"?

Tags: sega-genesis, sega

Can anyone help me?

Is there an Landstalker 2 or a "Look Like" on Sega Mega Drive?
Perhaps an "Fan-Made" - Thing?

I searched at Google - no results.

But I think, in the early 90s, there was an Landstalker 2 in production.

But no release? Why?

Comment: Alundra is the lansdstalker sequel for the psx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the the [German Wiki](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=de&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=auto&sp=nmt4&tl=en&u=https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landstalker_%25E2%2580%2593_Die_Sch%25C3%25A4tze_von_K%25C3%25B6nig_Nolo&usg=ALkJrhirA3meeMFhlyK-gSpqNGlaNffOgg#Fortsetzungen_&_Ableger) there was no game successor but a rather rare fan-manga called *"Landstalker 2 - Heart of Diamond"*. Maybe thats where  your memory is based on?

There where several games based on the same engine/principles on other systems, but no direct follow up.

Another candidate may be a revival in 2006, called [*"Landstalker 3D"*, for the PSP](https://www.unseen64.net/2008/04/08/landstalker-psp-cancelled/), but it got canceled. At least there is some [footage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2igJr2ZsNE) of a demo on some trade show.

Comment: I think you're right. But it's sad, that there is no Landstalker 2. I loved the graphic and music.

Answer (score 0):

I had Lanstalker 2.
I rented it from the video shop and played it on my Sega Megadrive (II).
Recently I've been trying to find the music to use as a ringtone, but after searching for it on google its as if it didn't even exist. Well, it did and I rented it for a total of 3 months - it was that good - and the music is firmly loged in my head.
Now I'm wondering why it's been erased from history???

I did never play LS1, but I did play a game where you had to collect McDonalds arches.
The two games would have come out roughly the same year.

Comment: Maybe whistle the music into an audio recorder or enter it into a program like LMMS and then upload what you get? It sounds like it could possibly be have been a bootleg of something with an unofficial title it may be easier to track it down through that avenue.